# Developing stream analytics job using visual studio tools - how to simulate metadata user properties?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-stream-analytics

I am testing my stream analytics job locally, using json files for inputs. 
My query uses metadata user properties using GetMetadataPropertyValue(T, '[User]'). How can I simulate these metadata properties in my input json file?

For instance I have the following input_messages.json

```
{
  "pressure": 34,
  "temperature":71
}
```

The device that is sending this message also adds some properties by doing

```
message.Properties.Add("Version", "1.0");
```

Now I am trying to simulate the same message along with its metadata properties in my json file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we do not support this scenario for local input file, but you can try our live data testing and connect to your input eventhub or iothub directly and GetMetadataPropertyValue should work well.

Comment: Follow-up question. Is there any way to perform unit-testing for my query if it uses the GetMetadataPropertyValue method?